# How to get person name while reading messages from device in android?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-contentprovider, android-contentresolver

I'm trying to get all messages from the user's phone, user number, text messages are retrieved successfully. But the problem is how can I get the UserName of the message sender saved in the user mobile device.

I'm getting the error **Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex("person")) must not be null**

Here is the method to get user SMS.

```
fun getSMS() {
        msgArrayList = ArrayList()
        msgArrayList?.clear()

        val uriSMSURI: Uri = Uri.parse("content://sms/inbox")
        val cur: Cursor? = contentResolver.query(uriSMSURI, null, null, null, null)
        while (cur != null && cur.moveToNext()) {
            val person: String = cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex("person")) // error in this line occurs
            val date: String = cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex("date"))
            val address: String = cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex("address"))
            val body: String = cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndexOrThrow("body"))
            val model = AllMessagesModel(address ,body,person,date)
            msgArrayList?.add(model)
        }
        cur?.close()

        allMsgAdapter = MessageAdapter(this, msgArrayList)
        val layoutManager =
            LinearLayoutManager(applicationContext, RecyclerView.VERTICAL, false)
        rvMessages!!.layoutManager = layoutManager
        rvMessages?.adapter = allMsgAdapter

    }
```

How can I solve this issue?

Comment: have you tried checking if there is in fact a column index being returned by `cur.getColumnIndex("person")` or setting a fallback for `cur.getString(...)`?

Comment: @ShayanShojaei yes I've checked column index not being returned by ```cur.getColumnIndex("person")```, but I read an article from I try to implement but it didn't work

Comment: So if I'm understanding this correctly, `cur.getColumnIndex("person")` doesn't necessarily return a non-null value. then I think you should be fine checking its value before passing it into `cur.getString` and setting your `person` variable to a fallback value (eg. the sender's number) in case the person column index happened to be null.